# Numpy weight averaging over index list value list

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying with getting average values with two paired lists - indices, values.

For who can't understand what I saying, it seems similar `np.bincount` for just counting item numbers. But in my case, taking average instead of counting.

For example,

```
input:
i = [0,  1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
v = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

what I want:
a = [10, 8.5, 6, 2.5]

# 10  for average of values whose i = 0: 10
# 8.5 for average of values whose i = 1: 9, 8
# 6   for average of values whose i = 2: 7, 6, 5
# 2.5 for average of values whose i = 3: 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Of course I know there is the simplest way, using FOR LOOP.
But my actual i and v are `numpy.ndarray` whose item number is approximately A FEW MILLIONS.
And it took super long time(it takes about minutes, but I have to iterate over and over)

I'd just tried something, but it didn't works. Someone may laugh for this :P

```
a = np.zeros(4)
a[i] += v
a /= np.bincount(i)
# I hope that "each v" is added to a["each i"], divided each numbers
```

And this is my last hope don't want to be used, FOR LOOP:

```
a = np.zeros(num_length, dtype=np.half)
n = np.zeros(num_length, dtype=np.int16)

for index, value in zip(i, v):
    a[index] += value
    n[index] += 1

a /= n
```

Comment: Simply : `np.bincount(i,v)/np.bincount(i)`.

Comment: WOW.... What a simple way.... thx!